# Images not displaying in certain browsers

Tags: html, wordpress, xhtml, image, xhtml-1.0-strict

having just completed first wordpress theme uploaded and working fine in FF, testing has revealed that the images in the following page do not display in safari and chrome.

http://www.isabelarbelaez.com/category/projects/so_it_goes

Anyone any ideas why? I cannot see why at all.

The images on the page display in FF, IE and Opera, just n ot safari or chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are floating within a table cell, and as such cannot enforce the height of that cell.

Your easiest option is to simply not float the images - this should inflate the height of the cell to match. There is no reason to float them as you currently have it set-up.

Your best option is to not use a table for this kind of presentation.

Comment: thanks for that. I got rid of the float and also added a set height to the table td - that seems to have worked. Cheers!!!